# hibernate changes id when saving the object

Tags: java, hibernate-5.x

I've got an object with this parameters

```
{
  "id"    : "36461dd3-2bdb-42de-8e3d-b44e28696b1e",
  "race"  : "HUMAN",
  "age"   : "18",
  "name"  : "Alisa"
}
```

I attempt to save it

```
List<MainFemaleCharacter> batch = Arrays.asList(sampleMainCharacter());
try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    batch.forEach(session::save);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

In debug, before saving, it shows `id` with expected value. But when I retrieve object it shows another id for example `dccaf5d0-5c2b-4336-a0f3-ff65f92bf5f1`. Why? `MainFemaleCharacter` class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="main_female_character")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@ToString(callSuper=true)
public @Data class MainFemaleCharacter extends BasicCharacter {
}

@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@ToString(callSuper=true)
public @Data class BasicCharacter extends UidNamedObject {
    @OneToOne
    private Race race;
    private int age;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public @Data class UidNamedObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: because ID value is `@GeneratedValue` i guess

Comment: Your `@GeneratedValue` updates by itself

Comment: @Jens @Nathan can I set it to generate if there is no `id` provided?

Comment: he should use `update` @Jens because it will save another object when he use `save`.

Comment: @Jens so there is really no way to save new object with already set id with generation if id did not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `@GeneratedValue` will generate an id automatically. It is the same as the   `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` annotation.

GenerationType.AUTO means that the persistence provider chooses a strategy which will restart the values after a server restart in your case.

I recommend you to consider using `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.

Comment: I wanted to supply application with entities with already predefined Ids - loaded from external sources and without id - created in-application for example.